# ASP.NET Core MVC 2.2 loses value in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am developing an MVC application on ASP.NET Core 2.2 platform. I have the following classes :

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
public class LoginModel : BaseModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public strinh Password { get; set; }
}
public class AccountController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        LoginModel model = new LoginModel();
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Test exception");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            model.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            return View (model);
        }
    }
}
```

and my cshtml file is like :

```
@model MyProject.Models.LoginModel
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var _err = $('#ErrorMessage').val();
    if (_err != null && _err != '') {
        alert(_err);
    }
});
</script>
<input type="hidden" asp-for="ErrorMessage" />
```

What I expect is to see the error after posting back to controller. When I debug I see that ErrorMessage property is set in controller, but value in hidden field is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the error was the hidden field was placed inside a form. Placing it out of the form did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put `ErrorMessage` in a hidden field which makes the round trip from client to server. Instead, you can simply use `@Model.ErrorMessage` anywhere in the view.